# Timezone issue in .NET

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-4.0, timezone

I'm on the east coast so my timezone is `Eastern Standard Time` which has an offset of `-05:00:00`. But I noticied when calling methods like `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` and `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()` it's only claiming that I have an offset of `-04:00:00`.

```
DateTime.Now
// 6/8/2011 8:08:26 PM

DateTime.UtcNow
// 6/9/2011 12:08:26 AM

DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
// 6/9/2011 12:08:26 AM +00:00

DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()
// 6/9/2011 12:08:26 AM

TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now)
// 6/9/2011 12:08:26 AM

TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now)
// -04:00:00

TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName
// Eastern Standard Time

TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time").BaseUtcOffset
// -05:00:00
```

As you can see even though it clearly says I'm in the "Eastern Standard Time" zone it's only calculating my offset to be `-05:00:00`. I've verified also that my windows clock says I'm in the correct timezone. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: If that's the case, how should I be taking that in to consideration when doing coversions?

Comment: http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/edt.html

Comment: Depends on what you're doing the conversions for. If they depend on EST, instead of your actual current right-this-moment timezone, use the one that gives you -5. Otherwise, use the ones that give you -4.

Comment: When I have written applications in the past that spanned various timezones, I found it easier to store the UTC date/Time as a opposed to storing the local time. This way all I need to do is to convert the time to the local time zone.

Comment: @Mark how do I do that if I want to convert the timezone on the server to the timezone of the user? Should that strictly be done client side or can I do the conversion properly on the server if I know what timezone the user is in?

Comment: @Micah - Yes, on the client side based upon their own local settings. Events only happen at one particular time regardless of where is occurred, you will only be standardizing the time that you use in your app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might have something to do with it being summer. Aren't you on Eastern Daylight Time now? That's UTC minus 4.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's -4 because it's currently daylight savings time.